# Bind dynamically value to component's props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have defined custom component with props. when I using this component I need dynamically bind value to on of these props

In custom component's template I have defined element like this:

```
<template>
...
    <div class="input-group-addon" v-show="currency">{{ currency }}</div>
...
</template>
```

and its prop:

```
export default {
   ...
    props: {
      currency: {
        type: String
      }
    }
   ...
}
```

And component's usage in another component:

component's template

```
<custom-component currency="calculateCurrency" ></custom-component>
```

component's code

```
export default {
   components: {custom-component},
   data: () => ({
      myProject: null // this is used as v-model in combo box
   }),
   computed: {
      calculateCurrency: function() {
          return myProject.currency; // currency is getter in object myProject
      }
   }
}
```

so in result I have something like this:
[image]

I also tried use

```
suffix=calculateCurrency
```

without quotes but didn't help. can you help me fix it please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a colon on the binding property:

```
<custom-component :currency="calculateCurrency" ></custom-component>
```

Adding that before "currency" will allow for data-binding